# dropdown list on showing selected item from list

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu

I have a dropdownList and it currently should be showing two items on list- when i am selecting the second one it goes back and shows the first item in the dropdown list.

This is my code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            DropDown.DataTextField = "DisplayName";
            DropDown.DataValueField = "ID";
            DropDown.DataBind();

        }
    }

<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDown" runat="server"AutoPostBack="True" DataSourceID="Sections">
            </asp:DropDownList>
            <asp:SqlDataSource ID="Sections" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:MyConnection %>" SelectCommand="SELECT e.DisplayName,  e.ID , e.GUID
                FROM .. e
                INNER JOIN .. re
                ON e.ID = re.anID
                AND re.otherID = 1">
            </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Comment: here's the reason AutoPostBack="True" in the drop down list. Remove this to prevent autopostback.

Comment: what does your `Page_Load` code look like are you checking for `ISPostBack`? what does your event for this code look like in your code behind file you can also investigate using the `__DoPostBack` method as well

Comment: @vendettamit but if i have a second dropdownlist and it populates depending on what was selected in the first dropdownlist - don't i need the AutoPostBack?

Comment: @DJKRAZE i don't have a Page_Load - The shown code adds information from database into the dropdownlist.

Comment: you didn't mention that in your question. Well to prevent it from being changed to default you need manage it on server side. As @DJKRAZE mentioned.

Comment: `Masriyah` what do you mean you don't have a Page_Load event.. check out this link are you sure you know what you are doing http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6w2tb12s%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Comment: @DJKRAZE I just updated my code but i am still getting the same situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove binding from design and try below code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        DropDown.DataSourceID = Sections;
        DropDown.DataTextField == "DisplayName";
        DropDown.DataValueField = "ID"; 
        DropDown.DataBind();           

    }
}
```

Thanks,
Hitesh

Comment: for `Sections` it is giving me a compile error stating that i cannot convert a SqlDataSource to a string

Comment: I was able to play around with it to get it displaying. but i am still getting the issue of when i am selecting an item from the first dropdown list that it defaults back to what it was.

Answer (score 0):

Just set your  Dropdown Auto AutoPostBack to False.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDown" runat="server" DataTextField="DisplayName" DataValueField="ID" AutoPostBack="False" DataSourceID="Sections">
            </asp:DropDownList>
            <asp:SqlDataSource ID="Sections" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:MyConnection %>" SelectCommand="SELECT e.DisplayName,  e.ID , e.GUID
                FROM .. e
                INNER JOIN .. re
                ON e.ID = re.anID
                AND re.otherID = 1">
            </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Check this Url based on your new query: [Populate one dropdownlist based upon action of another dropdownlist](http://forums.asp.net/t/1431726.aspx)

Best Regards

Comment: but if i have a second dropdownlist and it populates depending on what was selected in the first dropdownlist - don't i need the AutoPostBack?

Comment: In that case you will need Auto post back .